# py2exe TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, NoneType found

Tags: py2exe, fiona

Trying to get py2exe to compile a script for me that uses fiona.

Packages I use:

```
import os
import fiona
import sys
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
```

Then I end up with the following error after:

```
D:/Temp/project/python setup.py py2exe

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "setup.py", line 9, in <module>
  "excludes": ['bz2']
File "C:\Anaconda\lib\distutils\core.py", line 151, in setup
  dist.run_commands()
File "C:\Anaconda\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
  self.run_command(cmd)
File "C:\Anaconda\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command
  cmd_obj.run()
File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\build_exe.py", line 243, in run
  self._run()
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\build_exe.py", line 296, in _run
 self.find_needed_modules(mf, required_files, required_modules)
File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\build_exe.py", line 1333, in find_needed_modules
  os.path.walk(path, visit, packages)
File "C:\Anaconda\lib\ntpath.py", line 266, in walk
  names = os.listdir(top)
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, NoneType found
```

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You could try PyInstaller as an alternative. I was attempting to use py2exe but getting the exact same error you are getting. But then I installed PyInstaller (can be done through pip) and ran that and it worked straight away. Take care to remove any build/dist directories you have leftover from trying to use py2exe.

Note: I would have posted this as a comment as it in not a direct answer but I don't have enough rep.